# Why does javascript ignore the port of an url-string when creating the url-Object?

Tags: javascript, url, https, port

I want to read the port of an string of an `url` I have. I found out that you can create a new URL-object with the `urlstring` as an argument. Then you can call the port property of that object to get the port of the `urlstring`.

The port of my `url` is `443`. If I give a string with 443 as the port into the URL-object, the port-property of the `url-object` is `""`. If I choose other numbers as the port it works fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is a code-snippet:

```js
const URL_STRING1 = "https://example.com:443/";

let url1 = new URL(URL_STRING1);
console.log(url1.port);

const URL_STRING2 = "https://example.com:442/";

let url2 = new URL(URL_STRING2);
console.log(url2.port);

const URL_STRING3 = "https://example.com:444/";

let url3 = new URL(URL_STRING3);
console.log(url3.port);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`443` is default port for `https`

[`URL reference for full specs`](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-url-port)

```
....
--->   Set url’s port to null, if port is url’s scheme’s default port, and to port otherwise.
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
....
```

---

[`Default scheme reference for full specs`](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#default-port)

```
A special scheme is a scheme listed in the first column of the following table. A default port is a special scheme’s optional corresponding port and is listed in the second column on the same row.

scheme  port
"ftp"   21
"file"  
"http"  80
"https"     443
"ws"    80
"wss"   443
```

Answer (score 0):

This object is an experimental one, so you can trsut on it. Use a simple regex to extract the port -

```
const URL_STRING1 = "https://example.com:443/";
console.log(URL_STRING1.match(/https:\/\/example\.com:(?<=:)(\d{3})/));
```

Answer (score 0):

This unobvious observation seems to be mentioned in the javascript documentation:

> Note: If an input string passed to the URL() constructor doesn't contain an explicit port number (e.g., https://localhost) or contains a port number that's the default port number corresponding to the protocol part of the input string (e.g., https://localhost:443), then in the URL object the constructor returns, the value of the port property will be the empty string: ''.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/port